# DataTable draw daterange from vaadin-date-picker in polymer

Tags: datatable, datatables, polymer, vaadin-date-picker

I am try to implements datatables filter inside polymer from this link https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/2bkbx2y3/6/

But when I apply into polymer I found some issue when push to datatables a plugin method. in polymer I use vaadin-date-picker as datepicker, and here's my code :

1. HTML

   ```
   <template>
   <form class="form-inline m-b">
       <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
           <vaadin-date-picker id="min" placeholder="Start"></vaadin-date-picker>
           <vaadin-date-picker id="max" placeholder="End"></vaadin-date-picker>
       </div>
   </form>
   <table id="mainTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>STAD</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
   </table>
   ```
2. Script :

   ```
   class DataTableD extends Polymer.Element {
       static get is() {
           return 'data-table-d';
       }

       ready() {
           super.ready();

           var min     = this.$.min;
           var max     = this.$.max;

           //push method into search
           $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
               alert("min . ." + min) //min . .[object HTMLElement]
               var startDate = new Date(data[0].replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
               if (min == null && max == null) {alert("startDate . ." + startDate);}
               if (min == null && startDate <= max) {alert("startDate . ." + startDate);}
               if (max == null && startDate >= min) {alert("startDate . ." + startDate);}
               if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {alert("startDate . ." + startDate);}

               return false;

           });
           // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on                                
           min.addEventListener('value-changed', function() {
               window.setTimeout(function() {
                   max.value = min.value;
                   max.open();
               }, 500);

               this.$.mainTable.draw();
           });

       }

       _initializeDatatable() {
           if ( ! this.$mainTable) {
               // Make the jQuery object of the mainForm and arrivalTable.
               this.$mainTable = $(this.$.mainTable);
           }

           this._dataTable = this.$mainTable.DataTable({
           });
       }
   }
   window.customElements.define(DataTableD.is, DataTableD);
   ```

hope someone can share the idea to make it works, thx

===========================

Comment: I have doubt to use `Jquery` in  `Shadow Dom` ...See.https://robdodson.me/dont-use-jquery-with-shadow-dom/    `this.$.<id-name>' in order to acces the element with id. try also: `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#<id-name>);`

Comment: fortunately I have no problem's when use jquery. but the "push method into search" make data not display in table. there's an error at
"var startDate = new Date(data[0])" it return "invalid date"

Comment: Do you have a working sample as above link working with your code

Comment: unfortunately not yet, i just found solution for "invalid date" and found issue "min . .[object HTMLElement]" per on my latest update

Comment: I just wanted to know how you import Jquery into Polymer 2

Comment: here's @HakanC <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/vaadin-date-picker/theme/lumo/vaadin-date-picker.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../css/jasny/jasny.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../css/xy-datatables/xy-datatables.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../css/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="import" href="../../css/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

Comment: <script src="../../../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: Pls check this https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/exgdgL ( I receive undefined ext error with : `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(`

Comment: i have no point @HakanC, but it works on startD.addEventListener('value-changed', function() {} but not on this method $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {}

Comment: That's I meant, jQuery command gives error. But other is a basic Polymer's event listener. And it's working as it should work.

Comment: i try to use this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#<id-name>) per your suggestion and still face the same issue, anyway thx to make me realise this issue

Comment: I will review and re-write a working code for you with es6 n Polymer by today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below I tried to illustrate another way to filter :

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/exgdgL?editors=1011)

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady( ()=> {
  
class DataTableD extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
        return 'data-table-d';
    }
    static get properties() {
       return {
          minDate:{type:String },
          maxDate:{type:String }
    }}
    static get observers(){
       return ['_checkMinMaxDate(minDate, maxDate)']
    }
    ready() {
        super.ready();
    }


  _checkMinMaxDate(min,max) {
    console.log("Min-max:", min,max, this.items, this.xitems);
    var minn = min==="" ? "1000/01/01":min;
    var maxx = max==="" ? "2050/01/01":max;
    var newItems =  this.items.filter( (el)=> {
         return el.Startdate <= maxx &&
         el.Startdate >= minn ;
});
    this.set('xitems', newItems);
    
  }
}
window.customElements.define(DataTableD.is, DataTableD)

})
```

```html
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn-origin.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-date-picker/vaadin-date-picker.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn-origin.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-grid/all-imports.html">
 
</head>

<body>
<data-table-d id="tableDat" items="{{items}}"></data-table-d>
  
<dom-module id="data-table-d">
<template>
<style>
     vaadin-grid{
         height: 100%;
         font-size: 14px;
     }
     vaadin-grid:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
     }
</style>
        <vaadin-date-picker id="min" placeholder="Start" value="{{minDate}}" on-change="_checkMinMaxDate"></vaadin-date-picker>
        <vaadin-date-picker id="max" placeholder="End" value={{maxDate}}  on-change="_checkMinMaxDate"></vaadin-date-picker><br><br><br><br>
  
         <vaadin-grid aria-label="Companies" items="[[xitems]]" multi-sort>

               <vaadin-grid-column>
                 <template class="header">
                   <vaadin-grid-filter path="Name"> </vaadin-grid-filter>
                   <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Name">Name</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                 </template>

                <template>[[item.Name]]</template>
               </vaadin-grid-column>
           
               <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">
                   <vaadin-grid-filter path="Position"> </vaadin-grid-filter>
                   <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Position">Position</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                 </template>

                <template>[[item.Position]]</template>
               </vaadin-grid-column>
           
              <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">
                   <vaadin-grid-filter path="Office"> </vaadin-grid-filter>
                   <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Office">Office</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                 </template>

                <template>[[item.Office]]</template>
               </vaadin-grid-column>
           
               <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">
                   <vaadin-grid-filter path="Age"> </vaadin-grid-filter>
                   <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Age">Age</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                 </template>

                <template>[[item.Age]]</template>
               </vaadin-grid-column>
                    
               <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">
                   <vaadin-grid-filter path="Startdate"> </vaadin-grid-filter>
                   <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Startdate">Start date</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                 </template>

                <template>[[item.Startdate]]</template>
               </vaadin-grid-column>
                    
               <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">
                   <vaadin-grid-filter path="Salary"> </vaadin-grid-filter>
                   <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Salary">Salary</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                 </template>

                <template>[[item.Salary]]</template>
               </vaadin-grid-column>           

             </vaadin-grid>
  
</template>
</dom-module>
  
  
  
<!-- BELOW TABLE JUST FOR DATA TO PASS IN POLYMER -->  
<table style="display:none;" width="100%" class="display" id="example" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Startdate</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  
  
<script>
    var myRows = [];
    var headersText = [];
    var $headers = $("th");

    // Loop through grabbing everything
    var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
      $cells = $(this).find("td");
      myRows[index] = {};

      $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
        // Set the header text
        if(headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
          headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
        }
        // Update the row object with the header/cell combo
        myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).text();
      });    
    });
    var el = document.getElementById('tableDat')
    el.items=myRows;

  
  </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

**How to pass data outside Polymer**

```
_checkMinMaxDate(min,max) {

    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('date-changed', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: {items:this.items, startDate:min, endDate:max }}));
}
```

outside of the Polymer:

```
window.addEventListener('date-changed', (e)=> { 
     console.log(e.detail.items) // your items 
     console.log(e.detail.startDate) // Date to start 
     console.log(e.detail.endDate) // Date to end.
})
```

Comment: thx @HakanC you provide an alternative but I'm still looking for how date filter works in polymer's datatable. pardon me for very late comment

Comment: @masbrojo I didn't understand what exactly you mean with polymer's datatable But there are some other ways in order to make a filter.

Comment: it's js plugin @HakanC, so much jquery but since i'm working on maintenance phase. so, I can't make much change on current code.. here's the official doc : datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: @masbrojo So if you want to use Jquery codes, you may use it outside of the Polymer. I will edit the code above with 'How to pass data outside Polymer" title.  So, with an observer of the date change, `_checkMinMaxDate` functions firing. Soo, instead of doing some filter there,  pass the data outside of the Polymer. and handle with `data-changed` custom event. (see above) and after new filtered data, send it back into Polymer as I have already done above.