# How to use jQuery DOM element selectors in Polymer?

Tags: jquery, grid, jsgrid, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I was trying to implement jsGrid in Polymer but was stuck where it required to get the target grid DOM element to the `jsGrid()` function. Being unable to produce an equivalent to `$("#jsGrid")` in Polymer.

I have already imported all the required source files in the polymer component file itself using the `import` command.

// Render function

```
render(){
    return html`
      ${jsGrid_css}
      ${jsGrid_theme_css}
      <h2>Hello ${this.name}!</h2>
      <div id="jsGrid"></div>
    `;
  }
```

// Render grid method

```
renderGrid(){
    const gridEle = document.getElementById("jsGrid")
    const gridNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#jsGrid");

    console.log($("#jsGrid"))
    //--> output to this shows no element

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
          width: "100%",
          height: "400px",

          inserting: true,
          editing: true,
          sorting: true,
          paging: true,

          data:this.clients,

          fields: [
              { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
              { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
              { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
              { name: "Country", type: "select", items: this.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
              { type: "control" }
          ]
      });


  }
```

The grid is not being rendered on the html page when i am using `$("#jsGrid")` . This could be due to the fact that `jsGrid()` method is unable to get the DOM element with required properties when i replace `$("#jsGrid")` 
with `this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#jsGrid")` 
or with `document.getElementById("jsGrid")`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest natural Polymer element instead of jsGrid. See the example which I have used at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415546/push-filter-with-vaadin-date-picker-into-datatables-in-polymer/54473355#54473355

Comment: @HakanC  I tried the same with vaadin grid. Good example though 

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes some assumptions about how your page is built that were very useful in 2008, but don't play nice with modern libraries like Lit.

Firstly, `$("#jsGrid")` is basically `document.querySelector("#jsGrid")` with a load of wrapper functions. Back when jQuery launched `querySelector` had limited support and jQuery handled all the browsers for you, but this really isn't needed now.

jQuery existed long before Shadow DOM, and has no clue about it - you can't do anything with Shadow DOM and `$`, but you're on the right track with `this.shadowRoot`. Once you have the *element* jQuery doesn't need another query path, you can pass the element:

```
const gridNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#jsGrid");

$(gridNode).jsGrid({...
```

However, this will not be very stable - jQuery builds DOM inside the template LitElement has built, you need to ensure that DOM has been build before calling it (calling `renderGrid` from inside `firstUpdated` should be enough). LitElement may change the templated DOM, and when it does it might reset your grid.